# WSO2 Service chaining - Proxy services

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have a use case in which the request is send to a proxy A. It is then cloned to two different proxies viz., Proxy B & Proxy C.

The response from Proxy B & Proxy C has to be captured in the outsequence of Proxy A.

Will this logic work ? Because I get this error:

```
[2013-05-13 17:15:08,304] ERROR - ClientUtils The system cannot infer the transp
ort information from the /services/LIS/ URL.
[2013-05-13 17:15:08,304] ERROR - Axis2Sender Unexpected error during sending me
ssage out
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The system cannot infer the transport information fr
om the /services/LIS/ URL.
        at org.apache.axis2.description.ClientUtils.inferOutTransport(ClientUtil
s.java:81)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.DynamicAxisOperation$DynamicOperationCl
ient.executeImpl(DynamicAxisOperation.java:115)
        at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:
149)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.send(Axis2Flexib
leMEPClient.java:456)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendOn(Axis2Sender.java:57)

        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2Synap
seEnvironment.java:316)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator.mediate(SendMediato
r.java:92)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractLis
tMediator.java:71)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMe
diator.java:114)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.receive(Pro
xyServiceMessageReceiver.java:154)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEn
closingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:367)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclo
singRequest(ServerWorker.java:408)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.j
ava:219)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(Native
WorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
[2013-05-13 17:16:08,228]  WARN - TargetHandler Connection time out while in sta
te: REQUEST_DONE
[2013-05-13 17:16:08,229]  WARN - SourceHandler Connection time out after reques
t is read: 127.0.0.1:53170->127.0.0.1:8280
[2013-05-13 17:16:08,235]  WARN - EndpointContext Endpoint : LIS will be marked
SUSPENDED as it failed
[2013-05-13 17:16:08,231]  WARN - SourceHandler Connection time out after reques
t is read: 127.0.0.1:53169->127.0.0.1:8280
[2013-05-13 17:16:08,237]  WARN - EndpointContext Suspending endpoint : LIS - cu
rrent suspend duration is : 30000ms - Next retry after : Mon May 13 17:16:38 IST
 2013
[2013-05-13 17:16:08,247]  WARN - TargetHandler Connection closed by target host
 before receiving the request
[2013-05-13 17:16:08,250]  WARN - EndpointContext Endpoint : RIS will be marked
SUSPENDED as it failed
[2013-05-13 17:16:08,253]  WARN - EndpointContext Suspending endpoint : RIS - cu
rrent suspend duration is : 30000ms - Next retry after : Mon May 13 17:16:38 IST
```

My proxy:

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="hospital" transports="https,http,jms,local" statistics="enable" trace="enable" startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <property name="ContentType" value="text/xml" scope="default"/>
         <class name="com.test.custommediator"/>
         <clone>
            <target>
               <endpoint name="LIS">
                  <address uri="http://localhost:8280/services/LIS/"/>
               </endpoint>
            </target>
            <target>
               <endpoint name="RIS">
                  <address uri="http://localhost:8280/services/RIS/"/>
               </endpoint>
            </target>
         </clone>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
         <log separator="Entering Aggregator"/>
         <aggregate>
            <completeCondition>
               <messageCount min="2"/>
            </completeCondition>
            <onComplete xmlns:m1="http://services.samples/xsd" xmlns:m0="http://services.samples" expression="//m0:return">
               <send>
                  <endpoint>
                     <address uri="jms:/REPORT?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory&java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory&java.naming.provider.url=tcp://localhost:61616"/>
                  </endpoint>
               </send>
            </onComplete>
         </aggregate>
      </outSequence>
      <faultSequence/>
   </target>
   <publishWSDL uri="http://localhost:8280/services/LIS?wsdl"/>
   <parameter name="transport.jms.ContentType">
      <rules>                                                                                                                                                                                                               
         <jmsProperty>contentType</jmsProperty>                                                                                                                                                                                                               
         <default>application/xml</default>                                                                                                                                          
      </rules>
   </parameter>
   <description></description>
</proxy>
```

Any thoughts for me ?

Regards
Guru @gnanagurus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is correct. 
If this proxy is picking messages from a jms queue, set the following property in the inSequence before the clone mediator and try again.

```
<property name="messageType" value="text/xml" scope="axis2"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic and proxy conf is right..The issue is system cannot recognize the endpoint..
Your service URL is right?
can you make it like this? (remove the backslash at the end)

```
http://localhost:8280/services/LIS
```

Comment: Hello Ratha,I have tried that too. It didnt work. Is there anyother workaround ? - Guru

Comment: the causes for the above issue is, transport sender is not defined properly, or endpoint url is wrong..btw, what is the output you are getting from your classmediator..?

Comment: Class mediator returns a string Ratha. Also what else is missing my transport sender. I couldnt guess anything else :(

Comment: put a log =full before the clone, after the class mediator and paste the soap message and check the header values also.